# Query dynamoDB with IN operator on Partition Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table named products. It’s schema is

1. CustomerNumber (HASH Key of type String)
2. ProductID (Range Key of type String)

I want to query similar to

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE CustomerNumber IN ("cust123","cust234").
```

How to achieve it?

Few observations -

1. DynamoDBQueryExpression would query only on index/hashKey not not on list of hashKeys like in example above.
2. Also DynamoDBQueryExpression doesnt support IN , OR operator.
3. Also BatchLoad uses only Primary Key (in my case customerNumber 
   and productID)record to return batch of records.
4. Also ,I dont want to scan the table and apply filter on it.
5. Also creating GSI on customerNumber and then querying it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `select * where partitionkey IN ...` you would do a separate query equivalent to `select * where partitionkey= ...` for each value of your `IN` condition. It costs you a few extra round trips on the network, but that’s all; if you’re concerned about speed you can execute the individual queries in parallel.

Comment: Yep , thanks that answers the question . However how do you suggest to run queries in parallel , right now I am using parallelstreams in java.

Comment: Parallel streams is one way to do it. It’s hard to recommend a best way because there are so many factors involved (eg. memory, cpu cores, other loads on the system). You should finish building your application, and then do some performance testing/experimentation to see what the best option is for you. Oh, and remember, don’t optimize until after you have ensured correctness.